# HomePresence in Google Home Scripteditor doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, yaml, google-home

I am trying to trigger an automation by someone coming home or leaving. When I use "type: home.state.HomePresence" as a starter it returns an error that states that the house doesn't have "presence detection" and that I have to enable it in the Google Home app. However, this is certainly enabled and also working in the automations I made in the Google Home app.
Am I doing something wrong or is it related to a bug in the script editor?

```
metadata:
  name: Camera off
  description: Camera off when coming home, if between 8:00 en 23:00

automations:
  starters:
    - type: home.state.HomePresence
      state: homePresenceMode
      is:
        HOME

  condition:
    type:
      time.between
    before:
      23:00
    after:
      8:00
    weekdays:
      - MON
      - TUE
      - WED
      - THU
      - FRI
      - SAT
      - SUN

  actions:
    type: device.command.OnOff
    on: false
    devices: Camera Living Room - Living Room
```

I already tried turning the presence detection off and back on and also removed the other automations (in the Google Home app) that used the presence detection functionality, but this didn't help.

Comment: Presence Sense isn't triggering for me either

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this up. We couldn't reproduce this on our end. The "presence detection" error in Scripteditor means it wasn't properly set up in Google Home app. There are [few ways](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/10000312?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpresence-sensing-and-how-its-used-for-your-home-away-routines) to enable the presence sensing feature: by enabling your home to access phone locations and/or by using nest products such as Nest hubs, thermostats etc. to detect the presence. If you continue seeing the issue, please open a ticket in [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) and share more details on your presence sensing setup. I’m going to follow up with internal teams and update you through the issue tracker.